# How to redirect the user to some different page if user is logging for the first time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to redirect the user to some different page if the user is logging for the first time after registration.

For example: if a user is logging for the first time, then the user needs to redirect to the xyz.php page and if not, then the user should land up the index.php page. Never done something like this, So I have no idea about this.

and I know my code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You don't need to point out that. This is just for testing purpose

```
<?php 

session_start();

include 'db-connection.php';

   $user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user_email']);
   $user_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user_pass']);
   
   $select_user = "select * from users where user_email='$user_email'";
   $select_user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_user);
   $user_email_count = mysqli_num_rows($select_user_query);

   if($user_email_count) {
       $user_result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query);
       $user_db_pass = $user_result_array['user_pass'];
       $user_id = $user_result_array['user_id'];
       $user_name = $user_result_array['user_name'];
       
       if($user_pass === $user_db_pass ) {
           $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
           $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;

           echo "<span class='alert alert-success'>Login Successful</span>";
           header("location: index.php");
       }
       
       } else {
           echo "<span class='alert alert-danger'>You have entered wrong password</span>";
       }
       
   } else {
       echo "<span class='alert alert-danger'>No Record Found</span>";
   }

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: So... add a database column to flag the first login?

Comment: Typically you will want a column in your `users` table for `last_login_date` or `number_of_logins` and then you compare against that when they login.

Comment: I know you know, but anyway see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound/executed queries

Comment: So basically I need to insert zero (by default) in the number_of_logins column while registration and update it when the user logins, am I getting it right? @cOle2

Comment: Yes! I'm learning it! Once I got my hand on it, I will start using prepared statements with mysqli @Strawberry

Comment: @ShaktiGoyal Yep that's one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! you can answer the question if you want! I will mark it as an answered :) @cOle2

Comment: by the way, I found one more way to do it. We can also use the boolean value (0 and 1) 0 would represent that the user is logging for the first time and 1 would be the opposite of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you will want a column in your `users` table for `last_login_date` or `number_of_logins` or `has_logged_in` and then you compare against that when they login.

So in your `users` table either make the `has_logged_in` default to `0` (zero) or when inserting a new record make sure to set the value to `0`.

On login you would add an extra `if` statement to check this value and update the `has_logged_in` field:

```
if ($user_result_array['has_logged_in'] == 0) { 
    mysqli_query('UPDATE users SET has_logged_in = 1 WHERE user_id = '.$user_id);
    header("location: xyz.php"); 
    die();
}
```

I think you get the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! You are awesome :)